# Compare a file line by line and for those lines that meet the given requirement, print them

Tags: python, file

I have a txt file with content:

```
 577 181 619 216
 603 175 630 202
 651 180 681 202
 661 152 676 179
 604 176 630 204
 605 177 632 202
```

I want to read each line of this file and compare each line with one another and if for e.g. line i - line j <= 3 then remove that line and output only one between those lines.

For above content I want the output as:

```
 577 181 619 216
 603 175 630 202
 651 180 681 202
 661 152 676 179
```

In this case second line 603 175 630 202 falls under above condition so other 2 lines:5 and 6 are removed and only line 2 is written to output as given above.

```
f1 = open("result.txt", "r")
f2 = open("final.txt", "w" )
for line1 in f1:
    for line2 in f1:
        if each number line2 - line1 <= 3:
            #remove one of those line and write the remaining line to new file
            #f2.write(lines)
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

For example if you look at line 2, 5 and 6, each adjacent number in each line, the difference between is less then 3 i.e For line 2 and 5, the first element are 603 and 604 ( 603 -604 =1 i.e less then 3) and the second element 175 - 176 =1, 3rd element 630 -630 =0 and 4th element 202 - 204 = 2 i.e less then 3, all this falls under the given condition and hence for 1st and 5th line only one line is enough

Comment: I think you need to add a bit more clarity to this question

Comment: I agree, I would like to answer you if you better explain what the condition to remove a line is

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: "I want to read each line of this file and compare each line with one another and if for e.g. line i - line j <= 3 then remove that line and output only one between those lines. " => unable to understand this, and explain the output as well

Comment: Still doesn't make any sense. You have lines containing asterisks. How do you process those? When you say 'line i - line j <= 3' are i and j adjacent? Do you consider each line to be a single number (i.e., without asterisks or spaces)? Also, there doesn't seem to be anything in your code to handle the average calculation that you speak of

Comment: For example if you look at line 2, 5 and 6, each adjacent number in each line, the difference between is less then 3 i.e For line 2 and 5, the first element are 603 and 604 ( 603 -604 =1 i.e less then 3) and the second element 175 - 176 =1, 3rd element 630 -630 =0 and 4th element 202 - 204 = 2 i.e less then 3, all this falls under the given condition and hence for  1st and 5th line only one line is enough.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you need to convert the lines into the numbers.

With that, find absolute difference across the lines.

```
for i, line1 in enumerate(f1);
    nums1 = list(map(int, line1.strip().split())) 
    for j, line2 in enumerate(f1);
        if j <= i:  # skip repeating + equal lines 
            continue
        nums2 = list(map(int, line2.strip().split())) 
        diffs = [abs(nums2[x] - nums1[x]) for x in range(len(nums1))]
        print(f'Diff between {nums1} and {nums2}: {diffs}')  # for debugging 

        # check all the differences something like this... 
        if not all(d <= 3 for d in diffs):
            f2.write(line1)
```

Comment: There is an TypeError: object of type 'map' has no len()